# Error in batch merging images (x.tif is not a valid choice for "C2 (green):")

Tags: imagej, imagej-macro

I want to merge two sets of fluorescence microscope images into a green & blue image, but I'm having trouble with the macro (haven't used ImageJ before). I have a folder of FITC-images to be coloured green and a folder of DAPI-images to be coloured blue. I have been using this modified version of a macro I found online:

```
macro "batch_merge_channel"{
    count = 1;
  setBatchMode(true);
    file1= getDirectory("Choose a Directory");
    list1= getFileList(file1); 
    n1=lengthOf(list1);
    file2= getDirectory("Choose a Directory");
    list2= getFileList(file2); 
    n2=lengthOf(list2);
    open(file1+list1[1]);
    open(file2+list2[1]);
    small = n1;
    if(small<n2)
        small = n2;
        for(i=0;i<small;i++)
    {
          run("Merge Channels...", "c2="+list1[1]+ " c3="+list2[1]+ " keep"); 
          name = substring(list1, 0, 13)+")_merge";
          saveAs("tiff", "C:\\Merge\\"+name);
          first += 2;
          close();
          setBatchMode(false);
      }
```

This, however returns an error

> x.tif is not a valid choice for "C2 (green):"

with x being the name of the first file in the first folder.

If I merge the images manually, two by two, there is no error. So I'm presuming the problem is in the macro code. 
I found several cases of this error online, but none of the solutions that seemed to work for those people work for me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't solve this already, a great place to get help on ImageJ questions is the [forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).

I can suggest a couple of ideas:

- Is your image successfully opened by the macro? You could set the batch mode to false to check this.
- It looks to me like the `for` loop does not employ the variable `i`. It works on the first pair of
  images (`list1[1], list2[1]`), then closes the merged image, but then
  tries to process image 1 again.  To actually loop through all the
  images in the folder, you have to put *inside* the loop something
  like this (you don't need 'keep' -- better to leave it out so the source images will automatically be closed)

  `open(file1+list1[i]);
  open(file2+list2[i]); 
  run("Merge Channels...", "c2="+list1[i]+ " c3="+list2[i]);`

  -- Turning off batch mode should be done after the loop, not within the loop.

Here's a version that works for me.

```js
// @File(label = "Green images", style = "directory") file1
// @File(label = "Blue images", style = "directory") file2
// @File(label = "Output directory", style = "directory") output

// Do not delete or move the top 3 lines! They contain essential parameters

setBatchMode(true);
list1= getFileList(file1); 
n1=lengthOf(list1);
print("n1 = ",n1);
list2= getFileList(file2); 
n2=lengthOf(list2);
small = n1;
if(small<n2)
 small = n2;
for(i=0;i<small;i++)
    {
 image1=list1[i];
 image2=list2[i];
    open(file1+File.separator+list1[i]);
    open(file2+File.separator+list2[i]);
 print("processing image",i);
 run("Merge Channels...", "c2=&image1 c3=&image2"); 
    name = substring(image1, 0, 13)+"_merge";
 saveAs("tiff", output+File.separator+name);
 close();
 }
setBatchMode(false);
```

Hope this helps.